# Client caching recommendations for custom web fonts

Tags: iis-7.5, browser-cache, cloudflare

What is the best way to get IIS to set the headers for woff files so that they can be served from the client browser cache.

I'm working on an MVC .NET site that is hosted in IIS7.5, served through cloudflare with static caching turned on. The site uses a custom woff web font. When requests are made for pages that use these fonts IIS is serving them with the headers shown below. Subsequent requests all look the same. To me it looks like these are not getting cached by the client browser. I'd expect the server to be responding with 304 (Not Modified) and then the browser should serve the woff from its cache.

**Request Headers**

```
GET /blah/Content/fonts/AzoSans-Thin-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1
Host: blah.co.uk
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://blah.co.uk/bundles/Content/stylesheets/main?v=f9NXr53WMUdV9DfYJMkEU_5QZZi0g8eB1lB5lqxgdXc1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __cfduid=d96b367152ae58725c15e5946cf1d67f41415385741070; ASP.NET_SessionId=3tcc3e1nd0z005tlknrbph5h; redesign#lang=en
```

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 07 Nov 2014 19:27:57 GMT
Content-Type: application/font-woff
Content-Length: 27728
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Thu, 06 Mar 2014 10:40:46 GMT
ETag: "0cbfc872839cf1:0"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Fri, 07 Nov 2014 23:27:57 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=14400
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 185bee60092d0a90-LHR
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that cloudflare is changing the headers. If I bypass cloudflare I get 
Cache-Control:max-age=0
and the server responds with a 304 and the browser uses content from its cache.